# YDN-DB - How to update a record by id?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, ydn-db

I'm using YDN-DB as my indexeddb wrapper; I've read the user guide and api, and have absolutely no idea how you'd update a record by id (primary key [auto incremented]).

Is anyone familiar with this/have any idea?

http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out (finally) - thanks for the great library Kyaw!

The following code works:

```
record = {id: 1, "setting": "test", "value": "value"};
req = db.put({name: 'tblSettings', keyPath: 'id'}, record);
req.done(function(key) {
  console.log(key);
});
req.fail(function(e) {
  throw e;
});
```

Comment: Great. I was thinking you don't know the key to update the value.

Comment: Like many of the examples, this does not work for me.  I keep seeing little fragments and hints, and not a dozen working examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can update value of a record using `put` method by identifying the record by its primary key.

For store using auto generated key (autoIncrement), the primary key is known in the callback when you insert the record via `add` or `put` method. Primary key can be queried or canonically constructed. For example, a contact object may use its email address as primary key. You can get all primary keys in a store by `keys` method.

Comment: I did try this:

   db.put('tblSettings', { "setting": "test", "value": "50" }, 1);

This is the error message I got:

ydn.error.ArgumentException: key cannot provide while in-line key is in used.